# Delete spiders from scrapinghub

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy, scrapinghub

I am a new user of scrapinghub.
I already searched on googled and had read the scrapinghub docs but I could not find any information about removing spiders from a project. Is it possible, how?
I do not want to replace a spider, I want to delete/remove it from scrapinghub spider list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to remove the spider from your project, and deploy the project again, via `shub deploy`, or `scrapyd-deploy`.

Comment: thanks :) And when I want to add a new one, just paste it in project folder in pc and then deploy again the project right? it will deploy again all spiders inside project or will only add the one that is new?

Comment: Only spiders that are currently in your project will be added. Those that are missing will be removed. So, what you want to have on Dash, just put it in your project and deploy.

Comment: don't forget to remove both *.py & *.pyc files. if .pyc is present, it will still be deployed.